# Why are my Kubernetes HPA memory metrics incorrect?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, hpa

I'm trying to create HPA based on average memory utilization. But it always returns incorrect memory values.

My config:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: {{ include "kubernetes.fullname" $ }}-{{ . }}
  namespace: {{ $.Values.namespace }}
  labels:
    {{- include "kubernetes.labels" $ | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: {{ include "kubernetes.fullname" $ }}-{{ . }}
  minReplicas: {{ $.Values.autoscaling.minReplicas }}
  maxReplicas: {{ $.Values.autoscaling.maxReplicas }}
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: AverageValue
        averageValue: 30Mi
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 80
```

Results from `kubectl top pod`:

| NAME | CPU(cores) | MEMORY(bytes) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hpa-kubernetes-frontend-7969bdbdb5-2zr5p | 0m | 15Mi |
| hpa-kubernetes-frontend-7969bdbdb5-fb4sf | 0m | 16Mi |
| hpa-kubernetes-frontend-7969bdbdb5-fg2r4 | 0m | 15Mi |

Output from `kubectl get hpa -w`:

| NAME | REFERENCE | TARGETS | MINPODS | MAXPODS | REPLICAS | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hpa-kubernetes-frontend | Deployment/hpa-kubernetes-frontend | 185575651555m/30Mi | 1 | 3 | 3 | 18h |

Any idea why the memory value is `185575651555m`?

Comment: I don't know why it's reporting millibytes (that's a very odd unit just in general) but that value looks like about 18 megabytes (removing the last 9 digits) which is consistent with the other HPA settings.

Comment: Okey, it's clear now, thanks. But why is it increase replicas if it's below threshold value?

Comment: The [HPA formula](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#algorithm-details) is based in part on the current replica count.  By the formula and given the last output, 3 replicas * (18.5 MiB / 30 MiB) should give a target of 1.85 pods, which rounds up to 2; I'd expect it to scale in.

Comment: Okey, it's more or less clear now, thanks. It's steal an issue why it's 3 instead of 2, but I believe it can be a reason because some times memory utilization 21Mb

Comment: @Roman If you issue is resolved please share the answer so, that other community members can be benefited.